# Check Data Set for Null or Zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a table with 10 columns of floating values associated to a Serial Number.
Values can be entered or not in each column.
0 [zero] and NULL are not valid values.
Using SQL SERVER 2012.

My question is:
How can I check that given a specific serial number, none of these values is either 0 or NULL and return True if all values are present and False otherwise?
Please give me some suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: `return column1 && column2 && column3 && column4 ...` that's some pseudo code that probably is different in SQL.

Comment: You can alter table and specify constraints or also add a default constraint that will replace 0 [zero] and NULL value with a default value.

Comment: This is data loaded somewhere else by an instrument.  I can only deal with the values I find, not alter them.
Basically the test passes if all columns contain a value different from zero or null and fails in every other case.

Comment: if 0 or NULL are not valid values, why would they be in your table? shouldn't they be handled in the application layer? To handle NULL ensure the column is declared NOT NULL. To handle 0, I would suggest this is best done in your application?

Comment: You would do this with a query. Most likely using EXISTS. If you want some details about that kind of query you have to first provide details about your tables. That means posting the table definition, some sample data and the desired output. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: NOT NULL and NOT Zero are to verify a specific process has occurred.
As I said, the data is downloaded from an instrument and I have very little say on what the instrument can or cannot pass to the table.
The check occurs after the data load phase has occurred so I need to deal with the values I find.
If a specific set of columns contains values, then I can marck a specific test to have been performed otherwise I can notify the appropriate people of the missing test fact.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing this?   Do you not know SQL?

Answer (score 0):

More than your effort deserved but I was curious.  Cast to bit makes it a 1 or 0 and have to cast back to int to add.

```
declare @T table (int1 int, int2 int);
insert into @T values (null, null), (null, 0), (0, null), (null, 1), (10, null), (0, 0)
                    , (1, 0), (1, 10), (10, 0), (10, 10), (-2, -2);
with cte as
( select int1, cast(cast(isnull(int1, 0) as bit) as int) tf1
       , int2, cast(cast(isnull(int2, 0) as bit) as int) tf2 
    from @T
)  
select cte.int1, cte.int2 
     , iif(tf1 + tf2 = 2, 1, 0) as rr
from cte;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you paparazzo.
I have 10 floating values to check fv1...fv10 how would I count them so that I get 10 as a result rather than 2?
I tried:

Comment: Show some effort.  What you need is right there.  This is not a coding service.

Comment: Sorry I gave you that impression, I don't mind coding and effort, I'm just somewhat new to SQL.
I took your example and adapted to my case and it seems to work properly.
I will run a few tests with different datasets to confirm.
Thank you again!